# How to decrypt Twilio recording by passing Twilio audio url

Tags: c#, twilio

I need to decrypt the Twilio recordings on the fly (passing the Twilio recording url) without downloading the audio and after decryption I want play the audio in the browser when user click the audio url link.

I can see article to decrypt a Twilio recording file and getting a decrypted file. Does it needed to download all the file to decrypt it? Can someone help . Thankyou

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to decrypt a file, you will need to download it. You can't provide a user a URL to just get the file, because it will be encrypted and the only way to decrypt it is with your private key. You cannot supply that private key to a user either.

You could build an application that works as a middleware for the recording, so that when a user loads a recording it uses a URL of your application, which downloads the recording, decrypts it and then serves it to the user.

Comment: We need to show all the Twilio recordings links in browser and user can come and play in the browser .It works perfectly well until we use non encrypted recordings.  As recordings are stored in Twilio server we do not want to store it on our server.

Comment: Do you mean it works well until you use encrypted recordings? And that should not be a surprise, the browser cannot play an encrypted file. You will have to some more work around this to make this work the way you describe